# How to have only one longtable per page (starting at top of page) in latex?

Tags: pdf, latex, positioning, longtable

In my latex file I have some long tables that need to be split across two pages and I use the package longtable. Since I always want the tables to start at the top of the page, I also use the command "\afterpage" but it does not work. In fact, my tables are split across pages but while the second table starts at the top of the page, the third one doesn't. I also tried moving them in the text but that doesn't help either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, wasysym, ulsy}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc,title,header,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=3cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[round, sort, authoryear, longnamesfirst]{natbib} %longnamesfirst
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[frame]{crop}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{quoting}
%\usepackage{subfig}        
\usepackage[]{moresize}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{comment}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}

%\renewenvironment{comment}{}{} 
\newcommand {\red} {\color{red}}
%\newcommand {\black} {\color{black}}
%\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\green}{\color{green}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{RGB}{0,129,188}
\newcommand{\pink}{\color{magenta}}
\newcommand {\tsum} {\sum}
\newcommand {\tint} {\int}
\newcommand {\dsum} {\sum}
\newcommand {\bb} {\st\color{red}}

%\input{tcilatex}

%figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bbm}

%\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

%colors
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\black}{\color{black}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}


\makeatletter
\ifcsname phantomsection\endcsname
\newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[5]{}
\else
\newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[4]{}
\fi
\newcommand*{\addsubsection}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}%
    \subsection}
\makeatother


\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut

\newcounter{hypothesis}
\newcommand{\hyp}[1]{\refstepcounter{hypothesis}\label{#1}}


\usepackage[citebordercolor={1 1 1}, linkbordercolor={1 1 1}, urlbordercolor={1 1 1}, pagebackref]{hyperref}



\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ass}{Assumption}[chapter]


\allowdisplaybreaks[0]
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{1}
\renewcommand\topfraction{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{1}
\setlength{\floatsep}{6pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{12pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}

\fancypagestyle{MainBodyHeader}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    %\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} }
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textit{ \leftmark} }
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\rightmark}} }
}

\fancypagestyle{PlainHeader}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    %\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} }
}

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
hello 


\section{Tables and figures}


    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
        \caption{Marginal Effects}\label{does_tab1} 
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
        \cline{2-4} 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P(Y=1)} \\ 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        a   & 0.042^{***} & 0.035^{***} & 0.036^{***} \\ 
        & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.008) \\ 
        b & 0.022^{***} & 0.013^{***} & 0.026^{***} \\ 
        & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.008) \\ 
        c & 0.033^{***} & 0.036^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\ 
        & (0.001) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\ 
        d & -0.047^{***} & -0.037^{***} & -0.050^{***} \\ 
        & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.012) \\ 
        e &  &  & 0.00004 \\ 
        &  &  & (0.00003) \\ 
        f &  &  & -0.0001^{*} \\ 
        &  &  & (0.0001) \\ 
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        g & $No$ & $Yes$& $Yes$\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        h & $No$ & $Yes$ & $Yes$ \\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        Constant &  &  &  \\ 
        &  &  &  \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49,785} \\ 
        Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-21,475.640} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19,457.520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-18,845.390} \\ 
        Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42,961.280} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39,495.040} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38,274.780} \\ 
        \hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        \multicolumn{4}{p{.9\linewidth}}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01. \footnotesize long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long }  \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \end{longtable} 

\afterpage{
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \caption{Marginal Effects}\label{does_tab2} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cline{2-4} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P(Y=1)} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    a   & 0.042^{***} & 0.035^{***} & 0.036^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.008) \\ 
    b & 0.022^{***} & 0.013^{***} & 0.026^{***} \\ 
    & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.008) \\ 
    c & 0.033^{***} & 0.036^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\ 
    & (0.001) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\ 
    d & -0.047^{***} & -0.037^{***} & -0.050^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.012) \\ 
    e &  &  & 0.00004 \\ 
    &  &  & (0.00003) \\ 
    f &  &  & -0.0001^{*} \\ 
    &  &  & (0.0001) \\ 
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    g & $No$ & $Yes$& $Yes$\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    h & $No$ & $Yes$ & $Yes$ \\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Constant &  &  &  \\ 
    &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49,785} \\ 
    Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-21,475.640} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19,457.520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-18,845.390} \\ 
    Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42,961.280} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39,495.040} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38,274.780} \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \multicolumn{4}{p{.9\linewidth}}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01. \footnotesize long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text}  \\
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{longtable} 

}

\afterpage{
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \caption{Marginal Effects}\label{does_tab3} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cline{2-4} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P(Y=1)} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    a   & 0.042^{***} & 0.035^{***} & 0.036^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.008) \\ 
    b & 0.022^{***} & 0.013^{***} & 0.026^{***} \\ 
    & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.008) \\ 
    c & 0.033^{***} & 0.036^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\ 
    & (0.001) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\ 
    d & -0.047^{***} & -0.037^{***} & -0.050^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.012) \\ 
    e &  &  & 0.00004 \\ 
    &  &  & (0.00003) \\ 
    f &  &  & -0.0001^{*} \\ 
    &  &  & (0.0001) \\ 
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    g & $No$ & $Yes$& $Yes$\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    h & $No$ & $Yes$ & $Yes$ \\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Constant &  &  &  \\ 
    &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49,785} \\ 
    Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-21,475.640} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19,457.520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-18,845.390} \\ 
    Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42,961.280} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39,495.040} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38,274.780} \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \multicolumn{4}{p{.9\linewidth}}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01. \footnotesize long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text}  \\
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{longtable} 

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a one-file compilable [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid anything to go on the page below your table by adding `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, wasysym}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc,title,header,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=3cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[round, sort, authoryear, longnamesfirst]{natbib} %longnamesfirst
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[frame]{crop}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{quoting}
%\usepackage{subfig}        
\usepackage[]{moresize}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{comment}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}

%\renewenvironment{comment}{}{} 
\newcommand {\red} {\color{red}}
%\newcommand {\black} {\color{black}}
%\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\green}{\color{green}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{RGB}{0,129,188}
\newcommand{\pink}{\color{magenta}}
\newcommand {\tsum} {\sum}
\newcommand {\tint} {\int}
\newcommand {\dsum} {\sum}
\newcommand {\bb} {\st\color{red}}

%\input{tcilatex}

%figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bbm}

%\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

%colors
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\black}{\color{black}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}


\makeatletter
\ifcsname phantomsection\endcsname
\newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[5]{}
\else
\newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[4]{}
\fi
\newcommand*{\addsubsection}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}%
    \subsection}
\makeatother


\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut

\newcounter{hypothesis}
\newcommand{\hyp}[1]{\refstepcounter{hypothesis}\label{#1}}


\usepackage[citebordercolor={1 1 1}, linkbordercolor={1 1 1}, urlbordercolor={1 1 1}, pagebackref]{hyperref}



\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ass}{Assumption}[chapter]


\allowdisplaybreaks[0]
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{1}
\renewcommand\topfraction{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{1}
\setlength{\floatsep}{6pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{12pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}

\fancypagestyle{MainBodyHeader}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    %\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} }
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textit{ \leftmark} }
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\rightmark}} }
}

\fancypagestyle{PlainHeader}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    %\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} }
}

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
hello 


\section{Tables and figures}


    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
        \caption{Marginal Effects}\label{does_tab1} 
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
        \cline{2-4} 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P(Y=1)} \\ 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        a   & 0.042^{***} & 0.035^{***} & 0.036^{***} \\ 
        & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.008) \\ 
        b & 0.022^{***} & 0.013^{***} & 0.026^{***} \\ 
        & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.008) \\ 
        c & 0.033^{***} & 0.036^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\ 
        & (0.001) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\ 
        d & -0.047^{***} & -0.037^{***} & -0.050^{***} \\ 
        & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.012) \\ 
        e &  &  & 0.00004 \\ 
        &  &  & (0.00003) \\ 
        f &  &  & -0.0001^{*} \\ 
        &  &  & (0.0001) \\ 
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        g & $No$ & $Yes$& $Yes$\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        h & $No$ & $Yes$ & $Yes$ \\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        Constant &  &  &  \\ 
        &  &  &  \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49,785} \\ 
        Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-21,475.640} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19,457.520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-18,845.390} \\ 
        Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42,961.280} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39,495.040} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38,274.780} \\ 
        \hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        \multicolumn{4}{p{.9\linewidth}}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01. \footnotesize long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long }  \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \end{longtable} 

\afterpage{
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \caption{Marginal Effects}\label{does_tab2} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cline{2-4} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P(Y=1)} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    a   & 0.042^{***} & 0.035^{***} & 0.036^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.008) \\ 
    b & 0.022^{***} & 0.013^{***} & 0.026^{***} \\ 
    & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.008) \\ 
    c & 0.033^{***} & 0.036^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\ 
    & (0.001) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\ 
    d & -0.047^{***} & -0.037^{***} & -0.050^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.012) \\ 
    e &  &  & 0.00004 \\ 
    &  &  & (0.00003) \\ 
    f &  &  & -0.0001^{*} \\ 
    &  &  & (0.0001) \\ 
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    g & $No$ & $Yes$& $Yes$\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    h & $No$ & $Yes$ & $Yes$ \\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Constant &  &  &  \\ 
    &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49,785} \\ 
    Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-21,475.640} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19,457.520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-18,845.390} \\ 
    Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42,961.280} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39,495.040} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38,274.780} \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \multicolumn{4}{p{.9\linewidth}}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01. \footnotesize long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text}  \\
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{longtable} 
\clearpage
}

\afterpage{
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \caption{Marginal Effects}\label{does_tab3} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cline{2-4} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{P(Y=1)} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    a   & 0.042^{***} & 0.035^{***} & 0.036^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.008) & (0.008) \\ 
    b & 0.022^{***} & 0.013^{***} & 0.026^{***} \\ 
    & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.008) \\ 
    c & 0.033^{***} & 0.036^{***} & 0.037^{***} \\ 
    & (0.001) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\ 
    d & -0.047^{***} & -0.037^{***} & -0.050^{***} \\ 
    & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.012) \\ 
    e &  &  & 0.00004 \\ 
    &  &  & (0.00003) \\ 
    f &  &  & -0.0001^{*} \\ 
    &  &  & (0.0001) \\ 
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    g & $No$ & $Yes$& $Yes$\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    h & $No$ & $Yes$ & $Yes$ \\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Constant &  &  &  \\ 
    &  &  &  \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{51,878} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49,785} \\ 
    Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-21,475.640} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19,457.520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-18,845.390} \\ 
    Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42,961.280} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39,495.040} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{38,274.780} \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \multicolumn{4}{p{.9\linewidth}}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01. \footnotesize long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text}  \\
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{longtable} 

}


\end{document}
```